# How does Paper.js creates custom script tag for their Paperscript

Tags: javascript

I was looking at the tutorial of Paper.js from [here](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/) and saw this:

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
...
</script>
```

How do they manage to create custom script tag for their Paperscript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script is actually "ignored" by the browser. However, when (not shown in question) Paper is loaded, its paperscript method loads the innerHTML of the script tag that has the MIME-type "text/paperscript" and processes it. This is when the above script is used. You can view how they do this in their [source](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/99d7b5cfdbd03634afa1fe7e259992e707018ff0/src/core/PaperScript.js#L336-L370)

This allows paperscript to do some fancy operator overloading and scoping automagically.

Answer (score 1):

The script tag is standard. Only its "canvas" attribute is non-standard. There is nothing to stop you from using any tags and attributes, as long as you don't care about your HTML code passing a W3C validator. Under some circumstances you might encounter problems with non-standard tags in IE's strict mode, but a custom attribute shouldn't cause problems.